# Pass variable to .txt file

Tags: javascript, php, html, text-files

I am trying to pass a variable from  a html form to a .php script and then from the .php script into a .txt file where the variable value is stored. Problem is, when I test the scripts instead of posting the variable number it just posts the variable name "numberVariable".

### html/javascript

```
    <form id="payment-form" action="chargeCard.php" method="POST" name="payment-form">
                            <input onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" type="text" name="amount" id="amount" />
                            <input type="hidden" id="numberVariable" name="numberVariable" value="numberVariable"/> <!--this is where I try to pass the variable to the .php script-->
                            <input type="image"  src="Button1.png" id="customButton" value="pay" alt="button"/>

                            </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
                            function isNumberKey(evt)
                        {
                        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
                        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
                        return false;

                        return true;
                        }
                        </script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

                            var numberVariable= 1; //this is the variable I am trying to pass to the .php script to then pass the value to the .txt file

                            document.getElementById("numberVariable").innerHTML = numberVariable;
                            document.getElementByID("numberVariable").value = numberVariable;

                        </script>
```

### php

```
<?php 

    require_once('./stripe-php/init.php');

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("removed for safety");

    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
    $myAmount = $_POST['amount'];
    $describtion = $_POST['description'];

    $numberVariable= $_POST['numberVariable']; //this is where I get the variable from the form

    $myAmount = round((int)$myAmount*100,0);

    try {
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $myAmount,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $token,
    "description" => $describtion));

    //PASTE VARIABLE TO .TXT FILE START

    $filename = "iPhoneAuctionBids.txt";
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    $content .= $numberVariable. PHP_EOL;
    file_put_contents($filename, $content);

    //PASTE VARIABLE TO .TXT FILE END

    } catch(\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
    }

?>
```

Comment: first of all you have to move javascript codes after html elements. Because when they are being executed, the **numberVariable** doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you for the information, I have done as you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't do anything with the file.

You need to open the file and write that value to it.

```
$filename = "iPhoneAuctionBids.txt"; 
$content = file_get_contents($filename);
$content .= $numberVariable . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
```

Also you might want to wait for the html to be generated before you do any js processing on the DOM. Just put your JS code inside

```
window.onload(function(){
// here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited my script to be like in the following link, but now when submiting, it works but instead of the number it just writes the name of the variable "numberVariable "  http://pastie.org/private/mwoigoc208pzjpeffqfg

Comment: Can you post a link to you JavaScript?

Comment: I have tried to edit the javascript to be like in the following links but the problem is that it should work without putting a value in the input field and then assign the value outside in the javascript function but it doesn't work for me but if I then choose to put 1 in the value spot it works, so there must be something wron in the way I am passing the variable to .php
php: http://pastie.org/private/fbzm92prvem9mpvuscgzq
javscript: http://pastie.org/private/no4a224edvqbyubhdsixuq#20

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, you need to encapsulate your JS inside window.onload or else the input might not be there for you to put a value in it. like: window.onload(function(){ document.getElementById("numberVariable ").value = numberVariable ; }).  you don;t need the innerHTML part for an input field.

Comment: thank you very much for the answers, your way of doing it is right, I have just edited it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually open the file and write the new data to it. All you are doing is setting a local varianble with the filename, not opening it, nor fetching the contents. http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php is what you need to read first.